# Enabling GZIP compression for Firefox RSS reader

Tags: firefox, rss, gzip

I'm trying to view [an RSS feed](http://rss.binsearch.net/rss.php?max=50&g=alt.binaries.classic.tv.shows) in Firefox, but am getting the following message.

> Your RSS reader does not support (gzip) compression.

Is it possible to enable GZIP compression in the Firefox RSS Reader?

Comment: It works fine here, and http://echo.opera.com/ shows that Firefox accepts the `gzip` encoding.

Comment: Works fine for me. You may have a conflicting extension or plugin. Open Firefox in safe mode (Firefox button -> Help -> Restart with Add-ons Disabled) and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the "works fine" comments from [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity) and [Wk_of_Angmar](https://superuser.com/users/157124/wk-of-angmar).  I tested out the feed using Firefox on another internet connection, and things indeed work fine.

Turns out, the [corporate web filter](http://www.trendmicro.com/us/enterprise/network-security/interscan-web-security/index.html) alters the request, removing the "gzip" support.  This may be quite localized, but at the same time, if you are behind a web filter of any kind, that may be the issue.